# how to draw automatically indoor map in java 2d

Tags: android, xml, java-2d

I need to draw indoor map automatically when connect to the database. currently I am using java to draw indoor map.

```
while(rs.next()) {
            if(rs.getString(2).equals("line"))
                g2d.drawLine(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(3)), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4)), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(5)), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(6)));
            else{
                /*Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(".\\src\\Map\\"+rs.getString(2)+".png");
                g2d.drawImage(img1, Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(3)), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4)), this);
                g2d.finalize();*/
            }
        }
```

what i need to know is how to render that indoor map in android mobile. If i need to convert that output of java program to XML format and then what to do.All the process need to be automatically. Therefore what should i do. I am new to this and please guide me.

Comment: I would look into an open source library like AndEngine or [Skia](https://skia.org). You can check out a number of different libraries [HERE](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/1) that would definitely make it possible to get data from a database and render on screen. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. That means using this libraries can i directly render the map in mobile device through API. Which format that map should be. xml, jpeg or what?

Comment: Typically png format but there are other formats that are supported depending on the library including xml

Comment: Do you know how to render that png file in mapview. If so please guide me